# Hi i need to apply an increasing value to t so I can put it into A11. It should be from 0 to 1000 in single increments. Python

Tags: python, model, increment, ode

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(t,y,A11,A12,A13,A21,A22,A31,A33,D): #system of ODEs
  x,l,z = y
  dx1dt = A11*x - A12*l +A13*z + D
  dx2dt = A21*x + A22*l
  dx3dt = A31*x + A33*z

  return np.array([dx1dt,dx2dt,dx3dt])

h = 1
t_eval = np.arange(0,1000+h,h)
for t in range (0, 1001): #the section that need corrections
    t *= 1
A11 = (0.0211*h*(400 - t) + 0.211*h*(t - 400)) #my value t is supposed to go into this equation
A12 = 1088/87500
A13 = 7/200000
A21 = 20/1800
A22 = -20/700
A31 = 7/1800
A33 = - 7/200000
D = 49.3

x0=0
y0=0
z0=0

init_cond = np.array([x0,y0,z0])
sol = solve_ivp(func,[t_eval[0],t_eval[-1]], init_cond, t_eval=t_eval,args=                
(A11,A12,A13,A21,A22,A31,A33,D))

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0], label = 'Blood')
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[1], label = 'Tissue')
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[2], label = 'Bone')
plt.xlabel('Time (days)')
plt.ylabel('Amount of Lead (micrograms)')
plt.title('Kinetics of Lead in the Body')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Everything aside from the formatting for t and A11 is correct. The code should create a model which will consistently increase until it dip around t=400. I need to apply some function so that with each step, the value of t increases similar to t_eval but it needs to be able to be plugged into the equation to solve the ODE.

Comment: If you want `t` to go into `A11` equation at each step, why did you write `A11` outside the loop?

Comment: I tried having A11 in the loop but it kept producing an error